# Error retrieving field value from bean in JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Here's the background: I have a report, built with JasperReport and iReport. In it I'm trying to build an index with the help of a scriptlet. Here's the code of the scriptlet.

```
public class ToCScriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {

public String test(){
    return "WUBBA LUBBA DUB DUB!";
}

private static ArrayList<String> tableOfContentNames=new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<HeadingBean> headers=new ArrayList<HeadingBean>();

//  WE RETURN AN EMPTY STRING, SINCE WE INVOKE THE FUNCTION FROM A TEXT FIELD
//  THIS WILL MAKE SURE THE FIELD IS EMPTY, INSTEAD OF SHOWING "null"
public String addIndexName(String name){
    tableOfContentNames.add(name);
    return name+" added";
}

public String addHeader(String name,int pageNumber){
    headers.add(new HeadingBean(name, pageNumber));
    String result="";
    for(HeadingBean header:headers){
        result+=header.getHeadingText()+" "+header.getPageIndex()+" / ";
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Using it, I gather the index name and page number of each section that should be there. The information is gathered in these beans:

```
public class HeadingBean {

private String headingText;
private Integer pageIndex;

public HeadingBean(String text, Integer pageIndex) {
    this.headingText = text;
    this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
}

public String getHeadingText() {
    return this.headingText;
}

public Integer getPageIndex() {
    return this.pageIndex;
}

public void setHeadingText(String headingText){
    this.headingText=headingText;
}

public void setPageIndex(Integer pageIndex){
    this.pageIndex=pageIndex;
}

}
```

The index is in a sub-report in the last detail band that receives a data source created with the ArrayList in the scriptlet:

```
<subreport isUsingCache="false">
            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="595" height="25" uuid="2857c139-c43e-4180-bb0b-4f4fdd39dd91"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanArrayDataSource($P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getHeaders())]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreport_table_of_content.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

The sub report with the index is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report_transactions_subreport_platform_health" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="572" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" scriptletClass="userFunctions.ToCScriptlet" resourceBundle="JKpiReportLocalization" uuid="09b0093c-983f-49f8-bc81-7baf861acff5">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.331000000000001"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="30"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<template><![CDATA["report_style.jrtx"]]></template>
<scriptlet name="UTILITIES" class="userFunctions.UtilityFunctions"/>
<parameter name="NOT_IN_USE" class="java.lang.Number">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="headingText" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[headingText]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="pageIndex" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[pageIndex]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<variable name="CURRENCY" class="java.lang.String">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("CURRENCY").hasParameter("NAME") ? $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("CURRENCY").getParameter("NAME").toString() : ""]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="65" splitType="Stretch">
        <rectangle radius="0">
            <reportElement style="Subreport Section Title Background" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="10" width="595" height="30" uuid="abb4c5e4-ee6a-4620-9006-3b28cf3dc559"/>
        </rectangle>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement style="Subreport Title" x="0" y="0" width="595" height="50" uuid="e9158915-e6ef-40c4-804d-5ad272af9d5d"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                <font size="16"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[str("report.subreport.tableOfContent.title")]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="21">
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="83" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="fa959a40-465c-443d-8bad-bb4a8d449f29"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[str("report.subreport.tableOfContent.name")]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="401" y="1" width="100" height="20" uuid="61f77907-24fd-49cb-a5a5-48f02a9214c3"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[str("report.subreport.tableOfContent.page")]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="21">
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="83" y="0" width="318" height="20" uuid="b9f98ed4-24af-4c99-a753-044cae79a6ed"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{headingText}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="401" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="56eaf6f4-d1fb-49e9-bd2e-cfc06f208a4d"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pageIndex}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<summary>
    <band height="81">
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="595" height="20" uuid="25ff1c35-b0b8-4656-a01c-6603efa923a7"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.test()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="595" height="20" uuid="98c3cd2b-df00-4c28-aaec-549d8dd1797f"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getTableOfContentNames()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="595" height="20" uuid="5e6841ae-163b-4d3d-ae37-4f21f5440751"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getHeaders()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I looked around for what may be causing problems, but I couldn't find anything. I checked that the bean is public, the names are correct, but I just can't find where the problem is. Any help?

Comment: You need to debug it some, is the scritplet called?, is you method's of scriplet called?, who calls addHeader?, does the .getHeaders() contain anything? ecc, if you have some more info please edit your question.... like this it is impossible to answer

Comment: The scriptlet works fine. It grabs the headers correctly. The thing is, when I get the List and create a JRBeanCollectionDataSource, the sub-report generates an index, but wrongly, since it repeats the values, so I know the scriptlet is working fine. But when I try to create a JRBeanArrayDataSource, then the error comes up. I'm gonna try creating a DataSource straight from the script, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I used to create the JRArrayDataSource straight in the iReport, using the array as a parameter, and it would give an error. I tried creating a function in the scriptlet that would build and return de DataSource, and then I noticed that there are two instantiating functions, the common one I was using, and one with a boolean. I tried passing "true" in the boolean one, with the array, and it works now.